# command line arguments using python

Tags: python

I have this code that will let the user choose which file he wants to update by passing an argument in the command line, and then it do some more things but I have not included that here:

```
import sys
import os
from sys import argv

path = "/home/Desktop/python/test"
files = os.walk( path )
filename = argv[1]

if filename in files:
    inputFile = open(filename, 'r')
else:
    print "no match found"
    sys.exit()
    inputFile.close()
```

When I run the script it keeps giving me "no match found" but im pretty sure the file is there. I cant see what Im doing wrong

Comment: Use `os.listdir` instead of `os.walk` to get a list of files in `path` instead of a generator.

Comment: @Holt: but take into account you still need to use `os.path.join(path, filename)` to be able to open the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.walk()` returns a *generator*, one that produces tuples with `(root, directories, files)` values for each iteration.

You can't use that generator to test for a single file, not with a simple `in` membership test.

You'll also need to re-instate the whole path; you can't just open an unclassified filename without the directory it lives in. Just use a `for` loop here, and `break` once you found it. The `else` suite on a `for` loop only executes when you did *not* use `break` (e.g. the file was not found):

```
path = "/home/Desktop/python/test"
filename = argv[1]

for root, directories, files in os.walk(path):
    if filename in files:
        full_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        break
else:
    print "no match found"
    sys.exit()

with open(full_path) as input_file:
    # do something with the file
```

I added a `with` statement to handle the lifetime of the file object; once the `with` block is exited the file is automatically closed for you.

Comment: @Holt: thanks; was in a bit of a hurry, I knew I should have checked.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may use following code snippet.

```
import os.path
filename = argv[1]
path = "/home/Desktop/python/test/"
if os.path.isfile(path + filename):
   inputFile = open(path + filename, "r")
else:
   print "File Not Found"
```

Comment: This will check for `filename` in the current directory, not in `path`.

Comment: You really should use `os.path.join()`; it'll take care of such details as adding a missing path separator at the end, for example.