# How to use command line argument in python dataframe?

Tags: python, command-line

I am working with CSV file and in my code, for every CSV file that I want to process, I should change the input file name manually and it is taking some times to do that every time.

My code looks as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('data_0.csv', error_bad_lines=False);
```

I want to use the command line argument, to make the process easier and enter any CSV file that I want as an input.

for example:

```
python code.py data_0.csv
```

save by desire name. for example:

```
python code.py data_0.csv output_0.csv
```

Now, I already read many posts such as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038124/command-line-arguments-using-python), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033987/python-get-files-from-command-line), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482540/passing-arguments-to-python-script-from-command-line), but I am not sure which one is faster and easier. Python documentation has many options such as `sys.arg` or `argparse` but I couldn't able to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sys.argv would work for this problem:   https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

```
import pandas as pd
import gensim
import numpy as np
import string
from sys import argv

# read CSV input file
file = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], error_bad_lines=False);
```

""""
    Here my code performs some actions!
    """"

```
# Save the output into CSV
df.to_csv(sys.argv[2], index=True, mode = 'a')
```

(where sys.argv[0] here being code.py)

Comment: thanks for your comment. I tried to run as ```python mYcode.py data_0.csv``` but did not work. Also tried for  ```python mYcode.py data_0.csv, output_0.csv``` as well. Can you let me know how I should run with this? thanks

Comment: I tried and i am getting error as ``` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mYcode.py", line 34, in <module>
   file = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], error_bad_lines=False);
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined ```

Comment: apologies, its `import sys` not `from sys import argv`